# CSS Sibling selector doesn't work inside :not()

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I know that with pure CSS it's impossible to select previous siblings of the element. But I try to fool browser with a complex selector.
Please see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cj9g7hL5/1/). It contains several CSS rules that work fine except 2 of them:

```
//set border color to white for all elements before .selected and .selected itself
div:not(.selected ~ div) {
    border-color: #fff;
}

//set border color to green for the element previous to .selected
div:not(.selected ~ div):nth-last-child(2) {
    border-color: #0f0;
}
```

But seems that inside `:not()` sibling selector `~` doesn't work.
So there're 2 questions:

1. Is it expected that `~` doesn't work inside `:not()`?
2. Is there any work-around for such case?

**EDIT:**
The final idea is to make a nice hover effect with pure CSS like:
[image]
The hovered image is simply scaled, image to right of it could be found and styled easily but the left one... The example with divs is just an example.

Comment: I think that the only (pure css) way is to set all borders to white and then override the style for all elements after .selected. jQuery could also help you with index() and nth-child, but it would be a bit killing a fly with a bazooka

Comment: As per [(the specs here)](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation): Only simple selectors are allowed as arguments to `:not`. So, you cannot use combinators, only simple selectors.

Comment: One of the so many situations where you overthink and overdo something to achieve quite a simple result. Sometimes we come here with a not so _right_ solution and expect people to _fix_ it when actually by just exposing the original problem would bring quick and easy solutions. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:not()` pseudo-class could not contain sibling selector.

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors3/#negation

> The negation pseudo-class, :not(X), is a functional notation taking a **simple selector** (excluding the negation pseudo-class itself) as an argument.

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors3/#simple-selectors-dfn

> A **simple selector** is either a type selector, universal selector, attribute selector, class selector, ID selector, or pseudo-class.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to :

> set border color to white for all elements before `.selected` and
>   `.selected` itself

I would suggest to default the border color to white and change it after `.selected` :

```css
div {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    width: 30px;
}

div.selected ~ div {
    border-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<div class="selected">C</div>
<div>D</div>
<div>E</div>
<div>F</div>
<div>G</div>
```

For the second rule :

> set border color to green for the element previous to `.selected`

If you know wich one will be selected in advance, you can target the element before with `nth-child()` otherwise you will need some JS to select it.

An other approach if the `.selected` class is dynamicaly added would be to use the same mechanism (PHP, JS or other) to give a class to the privious element at the same time and apply CSS to that class.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible since CSS Level 4.

https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/

> The negation pseudo-class, :not(), is a functional pseudo-class taking a **selector list** as an argument.

Also it is changed from `:not( <selector># )` to `:not( <complex-selector-list> )` in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not#syntax in [November 2018](https://github.com/mdn/data/commit/a0d9efba5ec25a1bff4fa7e412c6ed29d8208f2c).

See browser compatibility for "Selector list argument" in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not#browser_compatibility.